# Objects Passing objects to Webservices

Tags: asp.net

C# ASP.NET

Hi
If you create an object with say 8 properties, if you then instanciated the object do you have to populate and use all properties before you can pass it to a webservices.

I have a program that that needs to collect report parameters from a user then store them in a database table so they can be called again later from a service.  I have 11 reports and they all use different parameters.  So my question is can I create a report parameter object that has 8 properties and only populate 5 of them leaving 3 properties empty for one report and then say populate 4 for another report and leave 4 empty or should I create an object for each set of report paranmeters?  Once I have that object can I then pass it to a webservice that persists the parameter data to the database with properties missing?

Happy to answer questions about this as I appreciate it is not that clear!

Cheers

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a collection with the parameter names and values instead?

Comment: So here is what I have inherited from another devloper at work:  I have an object called schedule that has all the common schedule data in such as next run time, date to run from / to etc.  He wrote this for one report that took no extra params.  We now have 10 new reports that have the above mentioned schedule parms plus these reports have filter params on such as status, description, and variuos flags.  I want to add these params to the existing scheule object and save them down at the same time as the rest of the schedule data.  What is the best design for this in your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it should be OK to do that.  As long as you control the interface to the web service, and it sounds like you do.

If you don't control the interface, then the WSDL of that interface will tell you if you can do it or not.

As long as your parameters are relatively generic, I would suggest the approach you describe.  Creating an object for each report type is going to get messy, and is unnecessary if the parameters are generic.

Comment: Hi Alan, I did do this but when the webservices was called I got a soap exception, saying boolean value xxxxx could not be null value type (can't remember exactly what the error was as I have now left work.  I will post the exact message here in a bit but thank you for letting me know this is possible)

Comment: The error I get is: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)

Comment: Right I sorted this, I had a different error on my page that was causing my webservice to fall over.  I am now managing to pass the object to the service without all properties set. Thanks for all your help!